# What happens when two app servers in cluster start LiquiBase update (via Grails)?

Tags: grails-orm, grails-plugin, liquibase

I am planning to use LiquiBase via grails database-migration plugin. When I start a cluster of two servers with a new version of the DB schema, and both servers attempt to start schema upgrade, what will happen?

Does either grails database-migration plugin or LiquiBase itself has protection against concurrent upgrade attempt?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but liquibase creates and uses a table to set a lock when a schema update starts and avoid concurrent modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to your database tables, Liquibase creates a `databasechangelog` and a `databasechangeloglock` table to manage its state. `databasechangelog` contains information about the migrations that you've already run, and `databasechangeloglock` is there to guard against concurrent attempts at running migrations.

When the first cluster instance starts up it will obtain a lock by inserting a row in the `databasechangeloglock` table, and run any missing migrations. When the second one starts it'll be blocked until the lock is freed, then it'll obtain a lock and since there won't be any un-run migrations, it won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you for you comment.Really I face same now. Do you know how to handle it?